# How can I configure an SSIS ODBC Connection Manager for an Oracle DB?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB using an ODBC connection manager in SSIS.  The ODBC DSN that I created works for MS Access, but when trying to create and configure a source task in SSIS, the following error message is displayed:

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.

> ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error
>   1114; A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. 
>   (Oracle in instantclient_11_2,
>   C:\oralce\instantclient_11_2\SQORA32.dll).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue?  Note that your error message has "oracle" misspelled in the path name.  Generally speaking, though, OLE works better than ODBC with SSIS.  If possible you might try the Oracle OLE DB provider, or if your versions match up I'd recommend the [MS SSIS OLE DB provider for Oracle](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bacon Bits.  I had to type up the error message manually, so that Oracle name misspelling was just a typo on my part.  And, I have tried configuring the SSIS connection manager using OLE DB as well without any luck.  The following error message is displayed when I tried that: Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available.

Comment: The following are all 32 bit: 
Windows 7 OS, SSIS, ODBC Connection Object & Oracle Client (according to the SQLPLUS_README file).